# Efficiently doing thousands of lookups in a single table via django's ORM?

Tags: python, django

I have two tables. Table A is in my local database. Table B is a series of records behind a rest API. I need to pull the data down from table B, find if it has a corresponding entry in my local db, and then modify that local entry with some additional information.

In pseudo python, it looks something like this:

```
all_records = my_rest_api.get_everything()
for record in all_records: 
  try: 
    u = User.objects.get(
       name=record.name, 
       other_thing=record.thing, 
       some_more_params=record.other
    )
  except: 
    pass
```

It takes an incredibly long time to do all of the lookups since we're doing a unique lookup on each iteration of the loop. Is there a good way to deal with this kind of pattern? Should I try processing these in batched so I can have giant where-clause-y queries..?

```
some_records = all_records[:100]
query = [Q(dynamically built query) for criteria in some_records]
Users.objects.filter(query)
# and so on..
```

Or is the first option my best bet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. The use of Q() for creating complex OR queries is the key. Try something like this:

```
import operator
qs = []
for r in all_records:
    qs.append(Q(name=r.name, thing=r.thing, more=r.more))
Users.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, qs))
```